# iOS user registration/authentication without signup (using Parse / Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, parse-platform

I'd like to create a user in Parse without asking the user to sign up. It is for a chat app built for iOS in Swift. I've heard that UDID is deprecated so cannot use that to uniquely identify user. I want to identify the user even if he/she reinstalls the app / changes device. I don't necessarily want to know any info on the user (email/mobile/etc), just to authenticate them and identify them with an account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using Login in Anonymously? and then after login, save the objectId of PFUser in Keychain. Before logging in check first for keychain if it has an objectId and use it to get the PFUser. Saving data in keychain will remain even if you uninstalled the app

```
PFAnonymousUtils.logInWithBlock {
(user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
 if error != nil || user == nil {
  println("Anonymous login failed.")
 } else {
   println("Anonymous user logged in.")
 }
}
```

Comment: I created a new PFObject, then used the object ID as the user ID for PFUser to ensure that it's a unique username. Is there a better way? Conscious that I'm making one call more than I need to in order to get the PFObject ID...